# EF6 Check to see if a Record exists for a specified Date

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am generating a statistics table for an already populated table . The EUR is the source table and Stats is the Destination Table.

I am wanting one row in the destination table for each day there are records in the source table.

I have this bit of code

```
 DateTime dt = date.Date; // Source Date
                    destinationRow =
```

`dme.Statistics.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DateString.Date == dt); // Does a row for` `this day exist?`

so I iterate through each row in the source table and get the `Date` I am then trying to see if the source table has a row for that `Date` - but EF Complains that I can not use `Date` within the Query.

**So how can I check the destination table for a row with a specific `Date` without querying the table twice. Once to get a `DateTime`, convert it and check and a further time to update or create the row?**

Comment: Take a look at the [TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(System.Nullable{System.DateTime})) method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D)) method like this:

```
var result = dme.Statistics
    .FirstOrDefault(d =>
        DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.DateString) == dt);
```

Comment: "but EF Complains that I can not use Date within the Query." Take out the .Date part and your answer is good.

Comment: Been so long I forgot all about the blooming DbFunctions !! :P